# Navigate to first screen in bottom tab navigation in reat native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have 2 screens in one Bottom stack navigator and 2 more screens in one of the bottom stack navigator screen.

**Order of screens**

- Home Bottom Tab

  - Home Screen
  - Record Screen
- About Bottom Tab

  - About screen

If I am on the record screen and I navigate to the about screen and by clicking the home bottom tab I will navigate back to the record screen but I want it to navigate me to the first screen in the home stack i.e home screen. How can I do that?

**Bottom Tab Navigator**

```
const HomeStackScreen = createBottomTabNavigator();

<HomeStackScreen.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
  <HomeStackScreen.Screen
    name={homeScreen}
    component={Home}
    user={props.user}
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
  />
  <HomeStackScreen.Screen
    name={aboutScreen}
    component={About}
    user={props.user}
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
  />
</HomeStackScreen.Navigator>
```

**Stack Navigator**

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

<HomeStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
  <HomeStack.Screen
    name={homeScreen}
    component={Home}
    user={props.user}
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
  />
  <HomeStack.Screen
    name={recordScreen}
    component={Record}
    user={props.user}
    options={{ headerShown: false }}
  />
</HomeStack.Navigator>
```

Comment: Try unmountOnBlur prop: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#unmountonblur

Answer (score 0):

put

```
unmountOnBlur={true}
```

in the options of Bottom Tab